# Load CSV file to MySQL server using Java

Tags: java, mysql, csv

I am struggling with loading a CSV file into a table in MySQL server. It gives me the working directory error, and I am guessing that

```
C://Users//SCSC//Desktop//district.csv
```

this is where I am typing in a wrong syntax. I have tried double back slashes, forward slash, but none of them works.

```
public void readCsvUsingLoad(Connection conn, String district) {
    try {
        String loadQuery = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C://Users//SCSC//Desktop//district.csv' INTO TABLE district FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (District_ID, A2, A3, A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9,A10,A11,A12,A13,A14,A15,A16);";
        System.out.println(loadQuery);
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.execute(loadQuery);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share the error you are getting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to confirm, you are running your MySQL server on the same server as you're running Java, right? MySQL loading only works if the file is on the DB server.

If you want to load a csv file from your local system into a remote MySQL server, you'll need to parse the file and run the insert commands.

You'll also need to make sure that the user running the MySQL server (mysql?) has read access to the directory containing the files.

Comment: I am running MySQL on the same server as Java. When I run the loadQuery statement in MySQL, it can successfully load the csv file. But I am having a trouble running the same statement in java.

Comment: When I first tried to run the loadQuery statement in MySQL, I ran into the same working directory error. So I moved the location of the csv files into my desktop, tried loading csv files, then it worked. Could it be the same issue for java? If so, should I move the .java file that I am working on to Desktop?